# Emacs paredit-mode -- how to correct unbalanced parenthesis in yanked code?

Tags: emacs, clojure, paredit

Occasionally I yank code into a `paredit-mode` buffer that is missing a closing parenthesis or bracket. `paredit-mode` then detects the unclosed expression and tries to add the missing paren in the wrong place. This is frustrating when I move the cursor to the point where I want the close paren but I can't put it there. I end up having to switch off `paredit-mode`.

Here's an example:
[image]

I've just yanked

```
[["https://github.com/aconbere/yesql.git"
 "aea69ebd4a7788a66fc8689fea7e806f1463c347"]
```

but `paredit-mode` sees a missing `)` at the very end (in red). I'm not even sure why it wants to use a close parens when the opening is a bracket. Typing `]` at the point makes the cursor jump to the end and try to fill in the red paren. Slurping or barfing don't have the intended effects and simply move the `)` around.

Is there any way to fix this without temporarily disabling `paredit-mode`?

Comment: Turning off `paredit-mode` sounds like a good idea, to me. ;-)  (But why stop with doing it temporarily?)

Comment: @Drew I happen to like it most of the time ;)

Comment: Yeah, I know. Some do; some don't.

Comment: Using ``mark-sexp``, bound to ``C-M-SPC``, to mark the region you are yanking can help avoid the problem in the first place.

Comment: Sometimes I am copying text from a website such as a README on Github.

Comment: Consider using something like [`expand-region`](https://github.com/magnars/expand-region.el) to select text semantically. This will help you copy balanced parens, so yanking shouldn't complain so much. Not a solution, but it might help to reduce the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`kill-region` (bound by default to `C-w`) and `quoted-insert` (bound by default to `C-q`) are unaffected by paredit mode. You can delete regions or insert matching delimiters using these keybindings, bypassing paredit rules. Remember that you can also turn off paredit, clean something up, and then turn it back on again.

Comment: One deletes an arbitrary region of text, the other inserts any character you like - I don't see what's missing there.

Comment: `quoted-insert` seems to be more of a way to type non-ASCII characters. I couldn't get it to paste text from the clipboard.

Comment: @ReedG.Law: Use `C-q`, then enter the closing bracket at the desired destination and paredit won't do the jump.

Comment: @LeonGrapenthin Ahh, I see now! Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I do not see a `quoted-insert` action any where in the IntelliJ config. I used the search boxes and I also manually checked under "Editor" and "Keymap"

Answer (score 6):

Others have already mentioned `C-q` for quoted-insert.  You can also use `C-u DEL` or `C-u C-d` to override paredit's normal balanced behavior of `DEL` and `C-d` for a single deletion:

`(foo)|)`

C-u DEL

`(foo|)`

Answer (score 3):

Trust me. By far the easiest is to **paste a bracket** or parentheses.

You can do:

```
    ;  ]
```

and then **copy** it

Answer (score 0):

When you have unbalanced parenthesis, navigate to the character position you wish to place the balancing parenthesis, issue `M-x quoted-insert` (bound by default to `C-q`), and then enter the balancing parenthesis.  `quoted-insert` will not prevent parenthesis from being issued.

Same idea as noisesmith said differently.  Turning paredit on and off is not an option :)